# How to pass over a pointer and allocate space on heap

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to deliver a char pointer to a function which then fills it with stuff so that the calling function could use it then. As it always gave me weird stuff in the calling function i wrote a simple representation about what I have done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bla(char *t)
{
    t = (char*) malloc(5);
    if (t != 0) {
        t[0] = 'h';
        printf("%c\n", t[0]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char b[10];

    bla(b);
    printf("%c\n", b[0]);
    return 1;
}
```

I'm not quite sure if it has something to do that C passes a copy of the argument. Do I need to pass a pointer to a pointer then or is there a better solution?

EDIT:

Sorry guys but I didn't get it. Could you please look over this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void blub(char **t)
{
    printf("%d\n", *t);
    *t = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    *t[0] = 'a';
    *t[1] = 'b';
    printf("%d\n", *t);
    printf("%d\n", *t[0]);
    printf("%d\n", *t[1]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *a;
    blub(&a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", a[0]);
    printf("%d\n", a[1]);

    return 1;
}
```

Output is as follows:

```
./main
6154128
140488712
97
98
140488712
97
0      <== THIS SHOULD BE 98 AS ABOVE!?
```

Why do i get 98 in the function blafu and in main it is a null pointer?! I am totaly confused :/

Comment: that code makes little sense...

Comment: Don't forget to free your memory somewhere!

Comment: @pluckyDuck - see my edit :) You're in the right dirction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use pointer to pointer.

```
//............vv
void bla(char **t)
```

Then use the pointer by dereferencing it:

```
// note the '*' in front of t
*t = (char*) malloc(5);
if (*t != 0) {
    *t[0] = 'h';
    printf("%c\n", *t[0]);
}
```

Also, declare `b` as `char*`, not as `char b[10]`.

---

Why? Because you're trying to change the pointer. The logic is the same as other types, but it's kinda confusing here.
Think about it like this: if you need to pass an `int` and you need to change it, you need a **pointer to int**. The same is here - you need to pass a **pointer to char** and you need yo change it, so use "**pointer to *pointer to char***" :)

---

***EDIT***:
According to your edit - yes, you have understood this perfectly, there's just a small problem - the priority of `operator*` and `operator[]`. If you replace your `*t[X]` with `(*t)[X]`, everythng will be fine :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use a pointer to pointer

```
void blah(char **t)
```

you can assign a chunck of memory (in the head) using malloc as

```
*t = malloc(size);
```

and you would call blah like this:

```
char *b;
bla(&b);
```

and it would be allocated and filled using in blah and the result could be printed in main.

Answer (score 1):

You were passing a pointer to to function. Through it, you can permanently change (after function returns) only the object it points to, but you cannot change pointer itself as it is it's copy that is actually passed to function. All changes inside function are made on the pointer's copy. Its original value remains unchanged when function returns.

(1) If you want to change some variable in some function, you need to pass its pointer to it. If that variable is of pointer type, then pass a pointer to it - a pointer to pointer! In your case, that variable will be of type char**.

(2) If you want to allocate memory on the heap in the function, you don't need to use the stack - declare pointer b as char*.

(3) After allocating memory on the heap, don't forget to deallocate it, otherwise you'll end up with memory leaks.

(4) Return 0 from your application if it terminates with no errors. Keep other return values 
for error codes - in case of different errors that might occur in your app, return different codes.

The final point is that this is a pure C application. In C++ you would use new/delete to allocate/deallocate memory, std::string instead of char* for strings, and std::cout << instead of printf for sending text to the output stream

```
void bla(char **pt)               // (1)
{
    *pt = (char*)malloc(5);

    if (*pt != 0) 
    {
        *pt[0] = 'h';
        printf("%c\n", *pt[0]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char* b = 0;                  // (2)

    bla(&b);
    printf("%c\n", b[0]);

    if(b)
    {
        free(b);                  // (3)
        b = 0;
    }

    return 0;                     // (4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `char b[10];` you have a statically allocated array, you don't need to allocate any more space for it, it is suitable to hold up to 10 `char` values.

If you want to let your function modify the contents of that array you just have to pass a simple pointer as you have done it (but without the allocation!):

```
void bla(char *t)
{
    if (t != 0) {
        t[0] = 'h';
        printf("%c\n", t[0]);
    }
}
```

After the function, the value of `b` in your `main` is also changed.

Comment: it was only a model for the real problem and there i need to use malloc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the result using a var reference then yes, you have to pass a pointer to a pointer, (or just return a result in the usual way, char* bla()).  Don't forget null terminators!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the strange behavior in the second example is the priority of operators.
[] (Brackets, array subscript) has higher priority than * (dereference)

So, `*t[1]` is the same as `*(t[1]).` You need `(*t)[1]`

as t is pointer to pointer to char:

`*(t[1])` means "take t's address, go (sizeof(char*)) bytes ahead, dereference the address, and dereference again"

`(*t)[1]` means "take t's address, dereference it, go (sizeof(char)) bytes ahead and dereference again"

Actually in the first case, the behavious is undefined, because it tries to double derefefence the location after t. In your example, the first value will be always printed, because t[0] means only dereference, so the two cases will be the same.