# C can't assign the value to the struct field

Tags: c

I'm trying to initialize the struct values with init() function.
It looks good but somehow it don't assign it when the execution of the init() function is over. Futhermore, inside the init() function everything is ok but when it returns the assigned values are gone. I spent a few hours but can't figure out what is happening.
Here is my code and struct:

```
typedef struct svm_data
{
    int num_points;
    int num_dimensions;
    double* training_set;    
    double* descision_set;   
} svm_data_t;

void init()
{
  init_data(&test_data);
  init_data(&check_data);

  printf("in init: test_data->num_dimensions: %d\n", test_data.num_dimensions); 
  printf("in init: check_data->num_dimensions: %d\n", check_data.num_dimensions); 
  set_correct_descision_set(&check_data);
}

void init_svm_data(svm_data_t* data)
{
  int np = 3;
  int nd = 3;
  data = (void*)malloc(sizeof(svm_data_t));
  data->num_points = np;
  data->num_dimensions = nd;

  data->training_set = (void*)malloc(sizeof(double)*(NUM_DIMENSIONS+1));
  data->descision_set = (void*)malloc(sizeof(double)*(NUM_DIMENSIONS+1));

  printf("test_data->num_dimensions: %d\n", data->num_dimensions);
}
```

This prints:

```
test_data->num_dimensions: 3
test_data->num_dimensions: 3
in init: test_data->num_dimensions: 0
in init: check_data->num_dimensions: 0
```

But I want it to print

```
test_data->num_dimensions: 3
test_data->num_dimensions: 3
in init: test_data->num_dimensions: 3
in init: check_data->num_dimensions: 3
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: I think the second malloc (for array init) is overwriting the first one (for struct init). Better use some kind of constructor.

Comment: The `data` parameter to `init_svm_data` is never actually used -- the third line of the function body simply overwrites the pointer that was passed in, having no side effects other than leaking memory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass over a pointer and allocate space on heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927036/how-to-pass-over-a-pointer-and-allocate-space-on-heap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = (void*)malloc(sizeof(svm_data_t));
```

Here you are assigning the return value of `malloc()` to the `data` variable, so it shadows (overwrites) its original value (i. e. the address of the struct you passed in). **You don't need this line at all,** since you already pass in the address of a (stack-)allocated struct.

Remarks:

1. [You should not cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
2. On the line you don't need, you actually loose the pointer to the `malloc()`ated memory when the function returns, so you even leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at a few lines here:

```
init_data(&test_data);
```

Here you call `init_data` (I assume it's actually `init_svm_data`) with a pointer to what I assume is a normal structure, i.e. you globally declare `svm_data_t test_data;`.

Then in `init_svm_data` you do:

```
data = (void*)malloc(sizeof(svm_data_t));
```

Here you *overwrite* the pointer you pass into the function.

This leads to a couple of problems: The first is that the pointer in `init_svm_data` is *local* to the function, so changes (assignments) to it will not be noticable outside of `init_svm_data`. The second problem is that you, if I guessed correctly with the declaration of `test_data`, do not need to allocate this memory as it's already done by the compiler.